# JAXB XJC code generation of element initializers with their declaration

Tags: jaxb, xjc

If I have a schema such as the following:

```
<xs:element name="Book">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="Chapter" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="Chapter">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Word" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="Word">
</xs:element>
```

It will generate something like:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Book")
public class Book {

    @XmlElement(name = "Chapter", required = true)
    protected Chapter chapter;
```

Is it possible to generate the following instead?

```
@XmlElement(name = "Chapter", required = true)
protected Chapter chapter = new Chapter();
```

This is so that even if an XML file is missing a Chapter element within a Book, when it is unmarshalled there will still be a Book object created so it is possible to do
book.getChapter().getWord() and retrieve an empty list, instead of checking for null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a plugin. I've written a [short tutorial](http://jaxbnstuff.blogspot.de/2013/09/creating-xjc-plugin-to-instantiate.html) that helps you do exactly that. Hope you find it helpful.