# Customize JAXB (xjc) binding compiler to instantiate list member with empty list

Tags: java, jaxb

Is it possible to generate code with the Java XML binding compiler ([xjc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/share/xjc.html)) that instantiates list members with an empty list instead of null?

**Example**:

*XSD-File FooBar.xsd:*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://foo.bar"
    targetNamespace="http://foo.bar" version="1.0">

    <xs:complexType name="FooBar">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="entry" type="xs:string"
                maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

running the binding compiler with this file, e.g.

```
xjc FooBar.xsd
```

produces the Java Source Code like this

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "FooBar", propOrder = {
    "entry"
})
public class FooBar {

    protected List<String> entry;

    public List<String> getEntry() {
        if (entry == null) {
            entry = new ArrayList<String>();
        }
        return this.entry;
    }

}
```

The entry list is instantiated with `null` and the null check is done in the getter method. But I need the entry mamber to be instantiated with the empty list like this:

```
 protected List<String> entry = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Is this somehow possible with customization? I did not find how?

Comment: I've noticed this too but it doesn't matter does it? The resulting xml from a null list or an empty list should be the same?

Comment: @BenThurley It is not about the XML in my use case. The class is used in other contexts where members must not be null (CORBA) and where the member value is derived from the member itself (possibly by reflection) and not via the getter method. So it would be fine if an instance of the class would have empty lists per default.

Comment: Poor you. ;) The only thing I can think of is potentially using the jaxb namespace in the schema to play with the bindings. A bit like this. http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/01/jaxb-and-choosing-list-implementation.html It may/not be possible...

Comment: @W A provides a link to a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13250913/367285) in his tutorial that he mentions in his answer. Might be interesting for others...

Comment: @BenThurley Thanks for the link. If I change the list implementation to `LinkedList` I exactly get what I need. Unfortunatly not when _changing_ the implementation to the default `java.util.ArrayList`. Arrgh!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, [Ben Thurley's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18609216/customize-jaxb-xjc-binding-compiler-to-instantiate-list-member-with-empty-list#comment27394844_18609216) is a good one. However, a different approach which I've been working on, but not completely finished is to create a plugin.

I've written a [short tutorial](http://jaxbnstuff.blogspot.de/2013/09/creating-xjc-plugin-to-instantiate.html), on how to create an XJC Plugin that allows you to instantiate fields.

Adding the following line:

```java
f.init(JExpr._new(co.parent().getCodeModel().ref(ArrayList.class)));
```

I was able to generate the following Code:

```java
@XmlElement(required = true)
protected List<Word> word = new ArrayList();
```

Again, not finished, but promising ;)

**UPDATE:**

In the `run()` method: Replace the following if-statement

```java
if (types.contains(f.type())){ 
    //If the type is defined in the schema
    //3. Instantiate
    f.init(JExpr._new(f.type())); 
}
```

with the following if-statement

```java
if (f.type().boxify().getTypeParameters()!=null && 
    f.type().boxify().getTypeParameters().size()==1){
        // f.type() is a list
        JType inner = f.type().boxify().getTypeParameters().get(0);
    f.init(JExpr._new(co.parent().getCodeModel()
            .ref(ArrayList.class).narrow(inner)));
}
```

And it will **correctly** instantiate an array list with parameterization.

What the if-statement here is basically saying, is that if this type is parameterized, and if the number of parameters is exactly one (two would mean its a map), assume its a list and instantiate it as an ArrayList. The method `narrow()` does the parameterization.

**UPDATE 2**:

Since creating the Plugin might seem like a lot of work. I've committed the plugin I've been working on to [GitHub](https://github.com/walmir/xjc-inst). This Plugin can now instantiate fields, lists (into ArrayLists), and even convert lists to Set!

All you now need to do, is get the plugin. Install it with `mvn install`. This add it to your pom file as shown in the Readme file on GitHub.

I think this is the closest you can get to a "possibility with configuration".

Have fun with it!

Comment: Thanks! Seems interesting and might be the only solution. +1 for the moment - still waiting for a possibility with configuration/customization ;-)

Comment: Thanks that you published your plugin on GitHub. I suggest that you add this information to this answer and delete the second answer as the information belongs together. Also, it would be best if you [pick a license](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/04/pick-a-license-any-license.html) for your plugin.

Comment: By the way [GitHub](https://github.com/blog/1530-choosing-an-open-source-license) helps you to choose a license ;-)

Comment: I tried using your plugin but am getting to see following error:
||---->>
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.codemodel.JPrimitiveType cannot be cast to com.sun.codemodel.JClass
 at de.jaxbnstuff.xjcplugin.ListInstantiator.run(ListInstantiator.java:46)

<<----|| Is it not supposed to handle the primitive data types if used in the schema definition?

Comment: For the ClassCastException reported in the previous comment, I made a fix and explained the same in the issues section of the Github page: https://github.com/walmir/xjc-inst/issues/1